# Meaning of URL parameters without value (e.g., "?id", "logout?out")

Tags: php, http, url, url-parameters

I know that if a URL has something like `http://example.com/test.html?id=2`, then the `?id=2` is used to send the parameter values to the server requesting the current page.
Now if the URL is something like `example.com/test.html?id`, what does this mean?

I see this in a lot of sites these days. What does `id` provide?
i.e the id does not contain any value, then why use it ?

Example: `example.net/eticketing/logout?out` - what does the `out` provide to the server site?

**PS:** Assume PHP is the server side scripting language.

Comment: PS: Sorry for wrong formatting, new here.

Comment: I edited your question and tried to clarify its title. Please check that I didn’t change your intended meaning, and feel free to [edit] it. You had, for example, used the [tag:php] tag, but you didn’t mention anything about PHP in your question. Are you only interested in interpreting such URLs with PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not really true in a strict sense that the query part of an url sends "values" to a server. Instead it is just a string that is *interpreted* by what ever processes that string on the server side, typically some scripting language.

Indeed typically some pattern like `name=value` will result in a variable called `name` holding the value `value`. But, as said, this is up to the processing step, it is not defined by some general standard.

There are a number of typical ways of how such a query string as you mention it, holding only some string but nothing like the pattern mentioned above, is interpreted:

- a variable is created, but not assigned any value, since none has been specified inside the query string. This *does* make sense, since the presence of a variable already is a statement in itself that can be evaluated, thus it can influence the processing step.
- the processing step can chose to completely skip the "typical" way such a string is interpreted and simply take over the value as given and do with it what it likes. That also *does* make a lot of sense, since typically such links are defined and handed out for usage by exactly the same processing step in a past request. So nothing speaks against that step to interpret the query in any way it thinks best suited.
- often such string is not even handed over to the final processing step (some server side scripting language). Instead it only serves the purpose to be evaluated in some rewriting rule taking place inside the http servers routing step. This is a very easy and convenient way to hand over runtime information independent of the concept of a variable.

So the bottom line is: this completely depends in the server side processing step.

Comment: I totally agree with you, but my main point is still that if `example.net/eticketing/logout?out` is used, what is the need of `out` as it does not carry any value ?

Comment: I don't understand the contradiction to my answer you appear to see... As written: the string 'out' can be a statement by itself. Obviously it also could be an artefact of faulty code, but in this specific example I'd say that no. 2 of the points I listed applies...

Comment: Thanks! I thought there might be some other methodologies where this has some deeper insight. But happy to know that there aren't. Thanks again.

Comment: Great that I could be of help!

Answer (score 0):

Parameter passed after `?` in `URL` is accessed via `$_GET`.

This is a `superglobal`, or automatic global, variable. This simply means that it is available in all scopes throughout a script. There is no need to do global $variable; to access it within functions or methods.

If you have a query string that contains a parameter but no value (**`not even an equals sign`**), like so:

```
http://example.com/test.html?id

<pre>
<?php
print_r($_GET);
if($_GET["id"] === "") echo "id is an empty string\n";
if($_GET["id"] === false) echo "id is false\n";
if($_GET["id"] === null) echo "id is null\n";
if(isset($_GET["id"])) echo "id is set\n";
if(!empty($_GET["id"])) echo "id is not empty";
?>
</pre>
```

I tested this with `http://example.com/test.html?id`, and it returned:

`id` is an empty string

`id` is set

So note that a parameter with no value associated with, even without an equals sign, is considered to be an empty string (**`""`**), isset() returns true for it, and it is considered empty, but not false or null.

Thanks.

Comment: I totally agree with you, but my main point is still that if   `example.net/eticketing/logout?out` is used, what is the need of `out` as it does not carry any value ?

Comment: @Anoosh, Nice question. here `out` have its own importance. it helps us to make check on something.Suppose you want to put check if `if(isset($_GET["out"])) {` do something `} else {` nothing `}`. So, it helps here.

Comment: Thanks for the above comment Rohit, was very helpful.